# Why can I not wire up my IBOutlets in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5, storyboard

I have a ViewController that has a couple of IBOutlet properties defined for UITextView. In the storyboard I have assigned my viewcontroller to the custom view controller. When I cntr + click on the viewcontroller I can see my two IBOutlets. When I try to drag them to the UITextViews on the storyboard they will not highlight and cannot be assigned.

I'm new to xcode 4.

Here is the property definitions from the viewcontroller:

```
@interface CreateUserViewController : UIViewController<UITextInputDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,retain) KeychainItemWrapper *keyChainWrapper;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *userNameTxt;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *passwordTxt;
```

These properties are synthesized in the implementation. I can assign each of the textfields' delegate to the viewcontroller without a problem. Am I missing any step?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the views you're trying to connect really are UITextViews and not UITextFields. It's not difficult to get them mixed up.